# CKEDITOR removed style text-align center of the td if table have align="center"

Tags: jquery, html, css, formatting, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor CKEditor 4.5.4. I have problem with formating. 
I think ckeditor removed the unnecessary style if its defined in the parent tag.

For example. Table have align tag. So if i try to align word "World" in second row CKEDITOR did not update the style because table have align tag.

Problem is when this html is render in the browser table align to left not center. how i can do ckeditor configuration to not removed style text-align formating.

```html
<table align="center" style="height:95%;width:100%;">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
   <table align="center" style="width:100%;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="width:80%;">Header</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="width:80%;"><span style="font-size:48px;"><strong><span style="color:#555555;"><span style="font-family:kondolar;">Welcome</span></span></strong></span></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `align` attribute anyways, it's deprecated in html5. https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html Can you give us a working demo?

Comment: I am not using align i think when user select the html table and format center, ckeditor add align="center".